# Sinatra - Log out button works but when you press back on browser it is still shows the logged in page?

Tags: ruby, session, sinatra, logout

I am logging out using a link to a logout controller as shown below

```
get '/logout' do
  protected!
  session[:id]=nil
  redirect back
end
```

`protected!` is a helper method:

```
def protected!
  redirect '/login' if session[:id] == nil
end
```

When I click on the logout button, the page logs out and displays the login page as expected. BUT when I click back on the browser, a page [that requires a session] is displayed when it should not be.

The session was set to nil in `/logout` and any pages that require a session should not display. Is there a cache or another session I need to destroy?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're being served stale content from the browser cache.

Depending on the browser and its configured settings, unless instructed otherwise (e.g. with a Cache-Control header) the browser will use its local cache when you press the back button.

You can use Sinatra's cache_control helper: http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sinatra/sinatra/Sinatra%2FHelpers%3Acache_control

Some [more info here](http://sinatrarb.com/intro.html) (under "Cache Control") and if you're interested, here's the [relevant RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.9)